# ERROR TO CREATE TABLE IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create this table in SQL,

```
CREATE TABLE `online_status` (
  `fk_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `last_activity` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`fk_user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

but is returning this error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY  (`fk_user_id`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM' at line 3

I've changed the commas, but the error continues. Can you help me on what is wrong?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`last_activity` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
```

should be

```
`last_activity` timestamp NOT NULL,
```